# Mental Ray render loss in Maya?

Tags: rendering, animation, scene-graph

The option in the rendering menu of Maya doesn't say "Mental Ray" anymore.
Please help me to get it back, or even a better plugin for Maya game quality rendering.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=maya+mental+ray+plugin) says that sometimes it "deactivates itself" and it has to be reactivated on the plugin manager (`Window > Settings/Preferences > Plug-in Manager`)

EDIT: According to [this other post](http://setdrivenkey.pdipierro.com/2010/02/tip-of-week-is-mental-ray-missing.html), Mental Ray's dll is called `Mayatomr.mll`

Comment: Mentalray.dll or something simular to that isn't in the folder at the plugin manager?

Comment: Sorry, is that a question?

Comment: @egarcia yes it is. Joris says that Mentalray.dll is not in the folder.

Comment: @Joris: I've edited my answer to include the name of the Mental Ray dll. I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: @Joris: if my answer solved your question, please mark it as valid by clicking on the "flag" on the left.